# Google reCaptcha not working after deploying to the QA server but works on localhost

Tags: recaptcha

I have built an MVC application. I have a Private Key and a Public key and I have registered my QA server domain, on the recaptcha site.

It works fine on localhost BUT the same exact code and same exact keys, errors out with "Invalid Input Captcha" error on the QA server. The images load fine, it also says "I am not a robot" BUT on the click of Save, it gives that error.

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong? I am using V 2.0. While registering a domain, am I supposed to include any patterns like *.mydomain.com?

I have just entered my domain in the format 'vt.st' (for e.g.) but my actual MVC site URL is test.other.vt.st/apps/mymvc.

I can't think of why it is giving that error after submitting.

Thanks in advance!
-P